# ArrayLinkedList Insertion Sort

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, insertion-sort

I have to do an Array List for an insertion sort and my teacher sent this back to me and gave me an F, but says I can make it up before Friday.
I do not understand why this isn't an A.L insertion sort.
Can someone help me fix this so it hits his criteria?
Thanks.

HE SAID:

After checking your first insertion sort you all did it incorrectly. I specifically said to shift the numbers and move the number into its proper place and NOT SWAP THE NUMBER INTO PLACE. In the assignment in MySA I said if you do this you will get a 0 for the assignment.

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;

 public class AListINSSORT {

     private static void insertionSort(ArrayList<Integer> arr) {
          insertionSort();
     }

     private static void insertionSort() {
        ArrayList<Integer> swap = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        swap.add(1);
        swap.add(2);
        swap.add(3);
        swap.add(4);
        swap.add(5);

        int prior = 0;
        int latter = 0;

        for (int i = 2; i <= latter; i++)
        {
            for (int k = i; k > prior && (swap.get(k - 1) < swap.get(k - 2)); k--)  
            {
                Integer temp = swap.get(k - 2);
                swap.set(k - 2, swap.get(k - 1));
                swap.set(k - 1, temp);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(swap);
    }
 }
```

Comment: What is the point of the `insertionSort(ArrayList<Integer> arr)` method that completely ignores its argument?

Comment: It will never enter your loop.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it seems your teacher asked you to use a LinkedList instead of an ArrayList. There is quite a difference between them.

Secondly, and maybe more to the point. In your inner loop you are saving a temp variable and swapping the elements at position k - 2 and k - 1 with each other. From the commentary this is not what your teacher intended. Since he wants you to solve the problem with element insertion, I recommend you look at the following method definition of LinkedList.add(int i, E e): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#add(int,%20E).

This should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see, your code does nothing at all.
The condition of the outer for loop

```
for (int i = 2; i <= latter; i++)
```

is not fulfilled.

As you start with `i = 2` and as `latter = 0`, it never holds `i <= latter`.
Thus, you never run through the outer for loop and finally just give back the input values.

If you add the input values to `swap` in a different order (not already ordered), you will see that your code does not re-order them.

Comment: Regarding "NOT SWAP THE NUMBER INTO PLACE", I think you wanted to do right. Your two for loops look as if you wanted to insert the number and not to swap it. Maybe, your teacher was just confused by the name `swap` of you list. So, think about just renaming it.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of stuff wrong here.

Firstly, your method:

```
private static void insertionSort(ArrayList<Integer> arr) {
   insertionSort();
}
```

takes an ArrayList and completely ignores it. This should presumably be the `List` which requires sorting.

Then in `insertionSort()` you create a new ArrayList, insert some numbers already in order, and then attempt something which looks nothing like insertion sort, but slightly more like bubble sort.

So, when you call `insertionSort(List)` it won't actually do anything to the list at all, all the work in `insertionSort()` happens to a completely different `List`!

Since on SO we don't generally do people's homework for them, I suggest looking at the nice little animated [diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort#/media/File:Insertion-sort-example-300px.gif) on [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort)

What you should have then is something like:

```
public void insertionSort(LinkedList<Integer> numbers) {

   //do stuff with numbers, using get() and add()
}
```